# Getting error in Android 5.1.1 for this - drawable.setAlpha(127);

Tags: android

I have used the below code for set alpha to scrollbar backgroundand getting error in Android 5.0 and 5.1.1.

Drawable loginActivityBackground = rootView.findViewById(R.id.mainrel).getBackground();

```
        loginActivityBackground.setAlpha(127);
```

Getting following error:

android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.setAlpha(int)' on a null object reference

Comment: background may be null

Comment: I think the background drawable is null , try the code on another activity and see if it works

Comment: android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.setAlpha(int)' on a null object reference
Clearly states that the Drawable is null. check if the drawable exists first.